# CSS float order is not as expected. Why?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a header in HMTL/CSS.

I have an image contained within a `<div>` element.  I wish this to appear on top left-hand corner of page.  To achieve this, I am floating the `<div>` element to the left AND listing the element FIRST in my HTML.  Its display property is set to `inline-block`.

I follow this with some text within `<h1>` tags.  This is also within its own `<div>` element. I have set display property of its `<div>` to `inline-block` and also floated it to the left.

Why then does the text appear to the left of the image?  If I have listed the image first, surely the image should be displayed BEFORE the h1 text.

Can someone please explain why this is happening?

```css
header {
  display: block;
}

.headerTop {
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 1.5rem solid #2B6868;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.75em;
  border-top-width: 5px;
  display: block;
  clear: none;
}

.headerTop_Logo {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: none;
}

#MyLogo {
  height: 40px;
  width: 341px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: none;
}

.headerTop_Title {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.headerTop_Title h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="PageContainer">
  <header>
    <div class="headerTop">
      <div class="headerTop_Logo">
        <img id="MyLogo" src="//via.placeholder.com/341x40" alt="My Logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="headerTop_Title">
        <h1>Service Model Pilot</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: May you post some code or an image with what youre trying to achieve? You can format code by either highlighting a group of text and pressing `Ctrl + K` to indent by 4 spaces or putting two tilde (`) between the parts of code.

Comment: Can you please post some sample code of what you have so it's easier to visualize what the setup? I'd be glad to help but it's hard to spot a problem without seeing actual code.

Comment: The way you describe it you get this: https://jsfiddle.net/Nebulosar/raj0nnn4/1 What is actually working

Comment: Isn't the text below the img?

Answer (score 1):

You are floating the `<img>` left, which is a child of `.headerTop_Logo`. So the image is only floated within its containing `<div>`. Floating `.headerTop_Title` left places the title to the left of its sibling, the unfloated `.headerTop_Logo`.

One suggestion is to use either `inline-block` or `float`, but not necessarily both. Below, I've set both `.headerTop_Logo` and `.headerTop_Title` to `inline-block` so they will appear horizontally next to each other.

```css
header {
  display: block;
}

.headerTop {
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 1.5rem solid #2B6868;
  padding:1em 1em .75em;
}

.headerTop_Logo {
  display:inline-block;
}

#MyLogo {
  height: 40px;
  width: 241px;
}

.headerTop_Title {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.headerTop_Title h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 28px;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="PageContainer">
  <header>
    <div class="headerTop">
      <div class="headerTop_Logo">
        <img id="MyLogo" src="//via.placeholder.com/241x40" alt="My Logo" />
      </div><div class="headerTop_Title">
        <h1>Service Model Pilot</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

---

Here's a floated example.
Notice the `.group` class that [clears the float](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) for the parent `.headerTop`.

```css
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

header {
  display: block;
}

.headerTop {
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 1.5rem solid #2B6868;
  padding:1em 1em .75em;
}

.headerTop_Logo {
  float:left;
}

#MyLogo {
  height: 40px;
  width: 241px;
  display:block;
}

.headerTop_Title h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 28px;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="PageContainer">
  <header>
    <div class="headerTop group">
      <div class="headerTop_Logo">
        <img id="MyLogo" src="//via.placeholder.com/241x40" alt="My Logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="headerTop_Title">
        <h1>Service Model Pilot</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```